# Change values of CSV based on user Response

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
Names, Size, State, time1,   time2,       
S1,    22,   MD  , 0.022, ,  523.324
S2,    22,   MD  , 4.32,  , 342.54 
S3,    22,   MD  , 3.54,  ,   0.32
S4,    22,   MD  , 4.32,  ,  0.54  
S1,    33,   MD  , 5.32,  ,  0.43
S2,    33,   MD  , 11.54, ,  0.65
S3,    33,   MD  , 22.5,  ,  0.324
S4,    33,   MD  , 45.89  ,  0.32
S1,    44,   MD  , 3.53   ,  3.32
S2,    44,   MD  ,  4.5   ,  0.322
S3,    44,   MD  , 43.65  ,   45.78
S4,    44,   MD,   43.54 , 0.321
```

Here is my code to reformat the data:

```
 import csv
 with open(r'C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\raw_inpuy.csv.csv','rb') as csvfile:
    reader=csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    first=True
     data={}
      column= input("What column do you want to see:  (x,y,z)")
       for row in reader:
             size = int(row[1])
             column = float(row[3]) # the problem lies here. I know that the column header plus row # must match but I do not know how to code it 

    if not size in data:
        data[size] = []

    data[size].append(column)


writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
writer.writerow(["Size", "S1", "S2", "S3", "S4"])
   for item in data:
    row = [item]
    row.extend(data[item])
   writer.writerow(row)
```

It outputs this to the csv:

```
 Size,S1,S2,S3,S4
 33,5.32,11.54,22.5,45.89
 44,3.53,4.5,43.65,43.54
 22,0.022,4.32,3.54,4.32
```

This is correct but it only displays the **time1** column but I want to be able to also see the **time2** column if I ask for it. **There is also a time3 column that I did not include**
 Even though I asked for the user input and declared it as a variable it still only prints the time1 column even if I ask for the time2 column.

Comment: you never use the input you get from `input("What column do you want to see:  (x,y,z)")` - instead you overwrite `column`. `time2` would be in `row[4]` of the `csv.reader`.

Comment: yes. but I want the user to determine what output they want to see. without me having to hard code the row number.

Comment: what about `col_nr = int(input(...))` and then  `column = float(row[col_nr])`?

Comment: so ask the user for  the column number instead of the header? What if they don't know the column number?

Comment: then consider the csv.DictReader (https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) - that way you can enter the name of the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this: (note that i had to strip the whitespace and the trailing comma from the first column of the csv... also note that there were some inconsistent commans left in your example csv)

```
import io
from csv import DictReader

csvfile = io.StringIO('''Names,Size,State,time1,time2
S1,    22,   MD  , 0.022 ,  523.324
S2,    22,   MD  , 4.32  , 342.54 
S3,    22,   MD  , 3.54  ,   0.32
S4,    22,   MD  , 4.32  ,  0.54  
S1,    33,   MD  , 5.32  ,  0.43
S2,    33,   MD  , 11.54 ,  0.65
S3,    33,   MD  , 22.5  ,  0.324
S4,    33,   MD  , 45.89 ,  0.32
S1,    44,   MD  , 3.53  ,  3.32
S2,    44,   MD  ,  4.5  ,  0.322
S3,    44,   MD  , 43.65 ,   45.78
S4,    44,   MD,   43.54 , 0.321
''')


reader = DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
first = True
data={}
col_name = input("What column do you want to see:  (x,y,z)")
for row in reader:
    # print(row)
    size = int(row['Size'])
    column = float(row[col_name])
    if not size in data:
        data[size] = []
    data[size].append(column)

print(data)
```

output (for time1);

```
What column do you want to see:  (x,y,z)time1
{33: [5.32, 11.54, 22.5, 45.89], 44: [3.53, 4.5, 43.65, 43.54], 
 22: [0.022, 4.32, 3.54, 4.32]}
```

---

**UPDATE**

you could then write that out with something like

```
import io
from csv import DictWriter
out_csv = io.StringIO('''''')

fieldnames = ['Size', col_name]
writer = DictWriter(out_csv, fieldnames=fieldnames)
writer.writeheader()

for key, value in data.items():
    row = {'Size': key, col_name: value}
    print(row)
    writer.writerow(row)

print(out_csv.getvalue())
```

this outputs:

```
Size,time2
33,"[0.43, 0.65, 0.324, 0.32]"
44,"[3.32, 0.322, 45.78, 0.321]"
22,"[523.324, 342.54, 0.32, 0.54]"
```

Comment: how would I output this to a csv.. when I try to I only get 2 columns 'Size' & 'S1'

Comment: also I dont want to hard code whats in the file into the io.StringIO

Comment: of course you do not want `io.StringIO` (you would have your real file pointer there); that just makes posting here easier. i added a way how might write that to a file (again, replace `io.StringIO` with your file handler). i just try to fill the gaps you did not know how to do - not write your whole code.